# Configuring Dummy addresses for forwarding and sending

Tags: mail

I'm switching over to a VPS for our hosting needs. Our users need a custom domain mailing address  that forwards to their emails and that they can send mails from. I have a setup with postfix which forwards their emails, but I can't think of a simple way to allow them to send with the same addresses without using full blown mail boxes. Any pointers?

Comment: Are you using cPanel or some type of control panel?

Comment: No, no control panel yet.

Comment: The easiest way would be to use cPanel. You could easily create any email address in seconds. Let me know if you need help. You can google my name.

Comment: cPanel would indeed make it much easier. Specifically with remote DNS situations....by adding "remote service IP's" for the DNS records, you can run mail on the domain(s) when its in a different zone/server/etc. By setting up forwarders after, it would use the correct routing without needing to do crazy switches.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all email clients allow you to send from alternate addresses.   I would make sure they know how to configure their email clients. Instructions for clients are pretty easy to find, here are a few:

- [Outlook](http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/set-multiple-email-identities-single-account)
- [Thunderbird](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Mozilla_Suite_:_FAQs_:_Mail_Aliases)
- [Apple mail](http://jonathan.tron.name/2006/11/05/multiple-identities-in-one-account-with-apple-mail-app)